# How to change the API ID in strapi?

Tags: content-management-system, strapi

I just started working on strapi. After created some collections, I want to go back and change the API id.

[image: API ID field is disabled]

But it seems that I cannot do that in the content-type builder.

If I need to change it, do I have to delete the whole collection and then start from scratch again?
Or is it possible to change some configuration to handle it?

I went through the documentations and also google. Cant find anything on the topic. I guess it may be possible to dig into the JavaScript and write my own API. but it doesn't make much sense to do that for such simple change.

Comment: not really, the `/api` bound to file structure, you have to rename each file, schema.json (also some filed in shema.json) and so on by hand. And that would erase your data

Comment: i can suggest creating new `/api`, copying your attributes to schema.json of new api, then copying data via rest, migration or bootstrap

Answer (score 2):

It is not simple but it *is* possible. In the API folder, you need to locate the folder that contains the collection you want to change. In your example, it will be /api/our-services-card.

Let's suppose you want to change it to our-service-card.

You will need to rename /api/our-services-car to /api/our-service-card. You will also need to rename our-services-card folder that will be inside of /api/our-service-card/content-types.

Then, you must change the schemas.json file contained in this last folder:

```
"kind": "collectionType",
"collectionName": "our-service-cards",
"info": {
  "singularName": "our-service-card",
  "pluralName": "our-service-cards",
  "displayName": "Service Card",
  "description": ""
}
```

Then, check rest of the folders to see if there are any reference to the old name. Restart strapi and that should work (it works for me).

Comment: It worked for me as well but only after playing around a lot. I think the better approach would be to create a new entity and copy the attributes inside the schema.json file. I will try that the next time ;-)